# Capistrano 3 Before and After Hooks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, capistrano3

I just switched to using Capistrano 3 and ran into some issues with the before and after hooks documentation.

In the docs it show the following for calling existing tasks

```
before :starting, :ensure_user
after :finishing, :notify
```

If I use this syntax I get 'Don't know how to build task starting'
Instead I had to do the following to get my tasks to work.

```
before "deploy:starting", "dj:stop"
after "deploy:finished", "dj:start"
```

The dj tasks are in Capistrano tasks directory in a *.rake file.
Any ideas on what I may be missing or do the docs need to be updated?

Ruby 2.1.6
Rails 4.2.0
Capistrano 3.4.0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can only use the shortcut version (`before :starting, :ensure_user`) when both tasks are inside the same namespace. When you want to execute tasks from different namespaces, you need to include the namespace inside the string (`before "deploy:starting", "dj:stop"`).

Comment: How to run multiple tasks?